# How do I get my -Project from View- image back in Blender v2.83?

Tags: uv-image-editor, motion-capture, motion-blur

We're doing a Motion Tracking project in class and we had to use Project From View for the UV on the building we intend to create the VFX meteor explosion, but when I went back into the Blender v2.83 file to continue my work, the picture is only a pink rectangle? (See below)

Since it's a school project, I can't move into any higher versions of Blender, but need to work within this v2.83 only. Also, we're in Spring Break, so I'm unable to ask my teacher how to fix this, but I need to complete it this week.

If anyone can help, please do, this is really the only part hanging me up as I do understand the rest of the assignment.  Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pink color means “missing.” The blend project cannot find the source image. Try using “find missing files“ and going to the new location of the image, or trying to put it back where it was before.

If the image or video clip is small, sometimes I pack it in the blind files so I can move it about without having problems.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try that and hopefully it'll show back up.